# Ogre difference between quaternion

Tags: c++, rotation, quaternions, ogre

I'm working with quaternion in ogre.
Each frame I get:

```
 Ogre::Quaternion prev;

 bool frameStarted(const Ogre::FrameEvent& event) {
   const Ogre::Quaternion q = object->getOrientation();
   if(abs(q.x - prev.x) > ...) {
      /* do something */
      prev = q;
   }
 }
```

How can I check if X-rotation at time T+1 is 180° less than X-rotation at time T?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get what you want to do with the x member of the quaternion. If anything you are comparing the x-coordinate of different rotation axes.

However if I get the question right, you are looking for the difference of rotation angles around the x-axis. In this case http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles explains how you can transform the quaternion into euler-angles which in turn will give you the rotation angles around each canonical basis vector (X, Y and Z). It then amounts to comparing the euler angles (keep in mind they'll be in radians, so use pi instead of 180).

Comment: Sorry, weekend's always a stressful encounter here. It is the last equation in section "Conversion" and there you are specifically looking for the value of phi (can be easily checked with an angle of pi and the x-axis, which yields the quaternion (0, (1, 0, 0)) and therefore the equation simplifies to a atan2(0, -1) which gives you pi as expected. So if you want to see if **the difference** of angle of rotation with respect to the x-axis is less than 180°, it would look like: http://pastebin.com/YwFF4Tvy